# Don't want BrowserPageTitle to be default with Menu Item Title name in Joomla

Tags: joomla3.0, page-title

How to disable the default value for the **Menu Item Title** in the **Browser Page Title**?

Answer (score 0):

You also can change this value, follow this simple steps:

- Go to your **Menu Item**,
- From here you can see a **Tab** called **Page Display**,
- Add your custom Title in the field **Browser Page Title**.

[image]